# Can I travel to Spain on Long Stay French Visa(Student) to attend International conference?

Tags: spain, study, long-stay-visas

I landed in Paris on Long Stay Visa and I am planning to attend one international conference in Barcelona, Spain. Can I travel on Long Stay French Visa (Student).